# Are there alternatives to LogMeIn Free and the free version of GoToMyPC that are free and licensed for corporate use?

Tags: remote, remote-control, remote-access, logmein, gotomypc

I'm looking to remote control a PC that's at our company behind a firewall.  LogMeIn Free and the free version of GoToMyPC do the trick but they're not licensed for corporate use.

**It's important** that the solution not require poking an outside --> inside hole in the firewall.  **I'd like the same or similar architecture as LogMeIn and GoToMyPC** where both the remote client and the PC to be controlled initiate outbound connections to the respective service's broker which arbitrates the connection.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted LogMeIn customer service and was surprised to find out that LogMeIn Free is indeed licensed for corporate use.  Of course has the limited feature set which could limit its usefulness in a company environment but if all you need are the basics then you're all good.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider UltraVNC [Nat 2 Nat](http://www.uvnc.com/addons/nat2nat.html).

Comment: Interesting, I'm gonna check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the host computer is Windows. Your options are probably limited if you want to avoid any firewall configuration AND it be licensed free for corporate use.

One program that might be worth a try is TeamView, but I think it fails the free for corporate use test.

Depending on your version of Windows, you might have Microsoft's Remote Desktop already included, but that might not work behind a company firewall.

Comment: Correct about Remote Desktop, it's a direct connection.  I was thinking about tools like CrossLoop http://www.crossloop.com but they require a person to accept the connection at the client that is to be controlled.

Comment: There's also another called BeamYourScreen, but I haven't touched that one for years.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [Back Orifice 2000](http://bo2k.sourceforge.net) as a remote admin tool, I hear it works well. It's Open Source under the GPL, so you could definitely use it in your corporation without licensing.
It uses port 31337, but there is a password protect, and it is supposed to be pretty secure (I haven't tried it out yet).